# Does jQuery jqGrid support horizontal scroll bar and frozen columns?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, horizontal-scrolling

I have a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) with a lot of columns, and it shows up like this when the sum of the column widths are bigger than the fixed width container:

[image]

Instead of having a horizontal scroll bar if the width of the grid is too big.

How can I get a horizontal scroll bar for jQgrid so there is a fixed max size of the grid and if I add more columns it will simply scroll?

Also, assuming this is possible, can you freeze the first few columns?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you use `forceFit:true` jqGrid option. First of all you should set `forceFit:false` or use  `shrinkToFit:false`. After that you can either use `width` option of jqGrid or use [setGridWidth](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to set grid width. You will have grid where the column header correspond to the `width` property of the column and the grid will have horizontal scrollbar.

**UPDATED:** Try to set `shrinkToFit:false` and `width:600` (for example) and see the results.

After setting only `shrinkToFit:false` you can see that the grid will have the horizontal scroll bar. You will see it even the grid is small enough to be displayed without the scrolling. It is a bug which I posted [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-calculation-of-the-width-of-the-grid-if-shrinktofit-is-false/) together with the corresponding bug fix. The fix is included in the the code on the [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/4ff226eed7434ee524c159226aca01c612b00ac2), but not included in the jqGrid 3.8.2. The next jqGrid release will have the fix. Nevertheless for your purpose the wrong width is not important because you will/can set the `width` of grid explicitly.

Comment: Hello.... I have added shrinkToFit: false and width property and the jqgrid fits the page, but no scroll bar apppears. Any hint, please? Thanks

Comment: @jstuardo: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which web browser in which version you use? Could you provide demo which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2):

you can get horizontal scroll bar with static or auto size fields by wrapping the grid and pager with a div and run a small script,
you can see the [jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/fQV7w/), or just go like so:

```
<div id="grid_container">
  <table id="list"></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

and run this script:

```
$('#grid_container div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
```

my example is using the script from trirand.com but iv tried it on their newest release and it worked just fine.
hope i've helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [fluid jqGrid plugin](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2009/08/21/creating-a-fluid-jquery-jqgrid.aspx). Maybe it helps you with your problem with the jqGrid width.

As for the second question, for freezing the first *n* columns I am successfully using this [super plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/new-freeze-column-plugin/) for freezing the first columns. You add only one attribute to your colmodel and it works.

Good luck!