# jqGrid Results overflow the grid

Tags: jqgrid, height, width, overflow, border

I'm working with jqGrid. The issue is that the results of the grid overflow the grid.

[image]

But I want to set a fixed width and height with a horizontal and a vertical scrollbar. I found this question already twice on stackoverflow:

**1.** [jqGrid Results over flow the grid and "Please, Select Row" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876950/jqgrid-results-over-flow-the-grid-and-please-select-row-message)

The question above was solved by loading "jquery-ui.js". Which doesnt helped in my case.

**2.** [Does jQuery jqGrid support horizontal scroll bar and frozen columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984969/does-jquery-jqgrid-support-horizontal-scroll-bar-and-frozen-columns)

I followed the answer of the question above and set the following options:

```
myGrid= $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
   ...,
    colNames: ['MATNR', 'ARKTX', 'KDMAT', 'KBMENG', 'VRKME', 'BRGEW', 'GEWEI'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'MATNR', key: true },
        { name: 'ARKTX' },
        { name: 'KDMAT' },
        { name: 'KBMENG' },
        { name: 'VRKME' },
        { name: 'BRGEW' },
        { name: 'GEWEI' }
    ],
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    forceFit: false,
    pager: "#myPager",
});
```

**3.** I also found an answer which suggested to set the width of every single column *instead* the width of the grid to see horizontal and vertical scrollbar:

```
    myGrid= $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    ...,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'MATNR', key: true },
        { name: 'ARKTX', width: 100  },
        { name: 'KDMAT', width: 100  },
        { name: 'KBMENG', width: 100  },
        { name: 'VRKME', width: 100  },
        { name: 'BRGEW', width: 100  },
        { name: 'GEWEI', width: 100  }
    ],
    //width: xxx,
    ...
 });
```

Additionally following scripts/styles are loaded:

```
// Scripts
jquery-1.10.2.js
grid.locale-en.js
jquery.jqGrid.min.js (Version 4.6.0)
jquery-ui.min.js (Version 1.11.2)
// Styles
jquery-ui.min.css
jquery-ui.theme.min.css
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gridContainer">
     <table id="myGrid"></table>
     <div id="myPager">
</div>
```

I tried it with IE11, IE10 and Firefox (v 33.1).

Unfortunately nothing of this helped. My desired scrollbars are not appearing.

**UPDATED:** I just provided a jsfiddle example - but that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/1082/

**UPDATED 2:** I noticed that removing the css *ui.jqgrid.css* in jsfiddle (External Resources) my problem can be reproduced! But I thought that there is no special style files for jqgrid? Am I missing something or why it isnt working with the default *jquery.ui.css*?

http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/1083/

Comment: One can't use `key: true` property for more as one column. Could you provide the demo (in jsfiddle for example) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I removed the property `key: true` but it didnt help.

Comment: Your demo shows that you forget to include `jquery-ui.css` which is required for jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file)). The fixed demo have no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/1084/. **IF THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED YOU SHOULD WRITE YOUR OWN ANSWER.** One have to read carefully the text of your current question to understand that the problem is already solved. It spends time of other people.

Comment: How can I mark my own post as solution? There is no checkmark to tick - just an favourite Icon :(

Comment: Two days later :) Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the file `ui.jqgrid.css` which is contained within the default jqGrid download folder. It was not enough to add `jquery-ui.css`.