# Cannot freeze columns in jQgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to restrict the scroll bars to certain columns of the jQGrid, for which I need to freeze other columns by setting the `frozen:true` and invoking `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns')` method.But these columns are not getting frozen. I am using `jQGrid 3.8.2`. I heard that it requires `jQGrid 4.4`, but if I replace the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` for 3.8.2 with the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` for 4.4.3, my grid becomes unresponsive. None of the existing functionalities work. It does not even make the `row` editable on click of it. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4985822/2065039)** might help you!!

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad.But this does not work for me..:(

Comment: Can you update your question with more code?

Comment: Also http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns does not mention anything about version limitations.